# Aws S3 and Mailchimp: Restrict access to Free Download for new subscribers to person, who actually received the "subscribed-email with download link"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mailchimp

I am providing free content (in form of a zip-file) that new subscribers get if they sign up via a shop website.

The free content is embedded into the campaign email with a weblink to amazon S3.
Of course, now anyone who knows the link can share it. In fact, I don't mind much. But I'm curious:

Can I restrict the S3 file via the public setting in that way, that only a person who accesses the link via the "successfully signed-up email" can download the free content?

I saw this code but what would be the www.example.com address? mailchimp? my campaign page on mailchimp? could not make it work...

help is appreciated, thanks

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an s3 pre-signed URL that only lasts for a period of time (say 24 hours).

That doesn't completely solve the problem; but it minimizes the surface area significantly.